# How can I make an iframe capture ONLY one element of a web page?

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I'm trying to capture `div#map-canvas` from my site, [www.RichBlocksPoorBlocks.com](http://richblockspoorblocks.com), to make an iframe that people can embed anywhere.

Here's my iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.richblockspoorblocks.com#map-canvas" style="width:600px; height:400px;"></iframe>
```

It goes to `div#map-canvas`, but it also loads the rest of the page as well. I'd like that div to be the only thing in the iframe.

Is this possible with an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, it would be easier to create a separate .php or .html document which contains only the parts that you want to show in the iframe and exclude everything else.

So, instead of the iframe pointing to "http://www.richblockspoorblocks.com#map-canvas", it would point to something like : "http://www.richblockspoorblocks.com/map-canvas.php".

This would be a very quick and efficient way of doing what you want, and doesn't require any outside libraries or javascript.

Comment: it's a loop problem, how to create a separate php document pointing to what i want knowing that i don't own the main domain

Answer (score 0):

When you call `http://www.richblockspoorblocks.com#map-canvas` the hash will probably cause the browser to look for a corresponding `<a name="foo">bar</a>` so this won't work using an iFrame.

What I would recommend doing is writing a script which you call from your iFrame which accepts the name of the page fragment to load. I know using jQuery's `$.load()` you can call an element ID to load a page fragment, and I think it's also possible in PHP too...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hash links in iframes.

You can and should use, few lines of you'r favorite server side language to create the specific content you want to render and then link to it. in that way, you'r server will send out to the end user only the desired data and also it saves bandwith and loading time.